# python-nose: how to trigger a custom callback on test failure

Tags: python-nose

I am using python-nose to run some tests.  The test code is arranged into modules, where each module's fixtures install some VMs in a new configuration, and the module's tests then check the behaviour of those VMs is what is expected.

I want to install a per-module failure handler that goes off and grabs the logs from the VMs if *any* test in the module fails.  Is there a proper way of doing that?  Is there some callback you can register with python-nose which will kick off custom code when a test fails?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should write a [plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html). You may be interested in defining [afterTest()](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html#nose.plugins.base.IPluginInterface.afterTest), [handleFailure()](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html#nose.plugins.base.IPluginInterface.handleFailure) methods on your Plugin class. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure I understand the idea.  Do I simply create a subclass of `nose.plugins.base.Plugin` in the python module under test which contains a `handleFailure` method?  Or is there something else I need to do to get `nosetests` to figure out that this is the action needed for tests that fail (in that python module)?

Comment: It doesn't look straightforward to me - but maybe I'm stupid.  They give plenty examples and docs on how to write a plugin, but I can't find anything explaining how you actually get nosetests to offer the plugin.